# Node js undefined in foreach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, craigslist

Hello I am using the node-craigslist package to scrape listings off of craigslist. I am having trouble processing my results.

```
client
  .search(options, '')
  .then((listings) => {
    listings.forEach((listing) => 
    console.log(listing.title),
    searchResults.title[counter] = listing.title

    );//end of listings foreach
  })//end of then listings
```

My issue is that only the first line of code in the listings.forEach actually work. So in this case, if I comment out the searchResults.title, it will print out the listing title. If I comment out the console.log and leave just the searchResults.title, that one will work. But they will never both work at once.

I must be getting the syntax wrong on this trying to do more than one thing in the for each.

Comment: Don't use `forEach`, use `for … of`. The mistake wouldn't have happened then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you should do the following:

```
client
  .search(options, '')
  .then((listings) => {
    listings.forEach((listing) => {
      console.log(listing.title);
      searchResults.title[counter] = listing.title;
    });//end of listings foreach
  })//end of then listings
```

You forgot curly brackets in your lambda expression.

Please read move about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thanks so much, cant believe I forgot something like that.